# Building a project with eclipse takes forever on windows

Tags: eclipse, macos, windows-xp

Does anyone know how to diagnose why eclipse (using Ant) takes over an hour to build a project on a windows box that takes a Mac only 3 minutes to build?

I've checked my eclipse.ini file and it is as identical as a Mac and Windows implementation can be.

Comment: Are there any other differences?  All the files are local to both machines?  Same Eclipse/Ant versions?